# Convert Bigint data to human readable date-time in Sql

Tags: mysql, epoch, bigint

I have created a `MySql` table and feed data therein with below code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DB (
    INN VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
    Time BIGINT not NULL
);
```

Now I want to get a table which will report the Maximum and Minimum values of `Time` when grouped by `INN`. Below is my code -

```
SELECT INN, from_unixtime(MIN(Time)), from_unixtime(MAX(Time)) FROM DB GROUP BY INN
```

I want to get the `Time` values reported as **normal date-time** instead of Epoch time. But with above code, I am getting `<NA>` values.

A typical `Time` value is like `1546380001264082944`

Can someone please help me to get the correct code to achieve the same.

Comment: Any chance of a little sample data to help with this?

Comment: Why are you storing a time as a BIGINT? Did you consider TIME

Comment: That does not look like a unixtime? What and how are you storing in that column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `1546380001264082944` is too big to be epoch seconds or even milliseconds. This is easily verified by putting this value on https://currentmillis.com/.

You have stored precision upto a nanosecond. So, divide the column value by 1e9 before passing them to `from_unixtime`.

---

```
SELECT INN, from_unixtime(MIN(Time) / 1000000000), from_unixtime(MAX(Time) / 1000000000)
FROM DB
GROUP BY INN
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is to do with the precision of the unix timestamp you are using.

Consider this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1546380001), FROM_UNIXTIME(1546380001264082944)
```

The output is:

```
2019-01-01T22:00:01Z    (null)
```

The timestampt value you have, 1546380001264082944, contains a level of precision beyond that accepted by MySQL.

The definition of `FROM_UNIXTIME` is:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp[,format])
```

The doc states:

> `unix_timestamp` is an internal timestamp value representing seconds
>   since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC

The precision of your timestamp is significantly greater than seconds since the Unix Epoch.

The docs are available [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).